# How to use setTimeout in CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

In CasperJS there is a function called evaluate which is a way for entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console, if i use setTimeout, setInterval or another async function it doesnt work as spected.

Some of the asked questions in StackOverflow use the wait function, but the wait function can't be used inside evaluate. I need to use a setTimeout because i'm scraping a grid with many pages so when i change to the next page i need to wait some seconds and that is the problem

Comment: Did you try "waitForSelector()"? http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector

Comment: But that doesn't work inside evaluate function

Comment: If the next page is opened anything that runs is disposed of including your timeout handler. That is why the management of the scraping/navigation procedure is done outside of the page context and not inside. You have to think differently.

Comment: You are right Artjom, thanks, well, i don't know what to do with this question because i don't need casperjs to resolve the problem anymore, i just discovered "pupperteer" it does not have problems with async functions inside evaluate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delay the CasperJS Environment through the Page DOM Environment.

In other words, you cannot use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) inside [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) to delay your CasperJS program.

It's better to use one of the following CasperJS functions to delay your program:

- [`casper.wait()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#wait)
- [`casper.waitFor()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor)
- [`casper.waitForAlert()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforalert)
- [`casper.waitForExec()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforexec)
- [`casper.waitForPopup()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforpopup)
- [`casper.waitForResource()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource)
- [`casper.waitForUrl()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforurl)
- [`casper.waitForSelector()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector)
- [`casper.waitWhileSelector()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitwhileselector)
- [`casper.waitForSelectorTextChange()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselectortextchange)
- [`casper.waitForText()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfortext)
- [`casper.waitUntilVisible()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waituntilvisible)
- [`casper.waitWhileVisible()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitwhilevisible)

Take a look at the diagram below to better understand how the two different environments work:

[image]
**Image Source:** [CasperJS Documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)